# Interactive program to selectively exclude parts of a diff file

Tags: linux, version-control, mercurial, mercurial-queue

Is there a program (preferably available on Cygwin) which I can use to "filter" a diff file  interactively? i.e. I want something like git interactive add, except that I want to operate on a diff file. I have already discovered `filterdiff`, but I don't think that it supports interactive editing, only inclusion/exclusion of hunks based on a pre-defined search criteria.

My usage scenario: I have a patch in MQ, which I would like to split up per the tutorial here: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqTutorial#Split_a_patch_into_multiple_patches. In order to do so, I have to edit a patch file so that it includes only the (many) changes I want, and doing this manually with a text editor is kind of a pain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably get what you want using the record extension: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RecordExtension

Apply the patch (but don't commit it) and then selectively commit chunk by chunk using record.  You could do that with or without mq in the works.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this! I eventually got what I wanted using a combination of the record extension, reapplying the full patch, and manually fixing bad hunks, but it would have been nice to have a GUI tool or something. (In particular, I wanted to keep/extract individual lines in several hunks.)

Answer (score 0):

Emacs’ `diff-mode` has commands to (un)apply or delete individual hunks of a diff.  It also allows **editing** the hunks (keeping the hunk headers up to date automatically), and it has a hunk-**split** command that is a bit more powerful than that in `git add -p`.